# How to extract multiple 5-minute averages from a data frame based on specified start time?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, extract, average, openair

I have second-by-second data for channels A, B, and C as shown below (this just shows the first 6 rows):

```
                 date        A        B        C
1 2020-03-06 09:55:42 224.3763 222.3763 226.3763
2 2020-03-06 09:55:43 224.2221 222.2221 226.2221
3 2020-03-06 09:55:44 224.2239 222.2239 226.2239
4 2020-03-06 09:55:45 224.2044 222.2044 226.2044
5 2020-03-06 09:55:46 224.2397 222.2397 226.2397
6 2020-03-06 09:55:47 224.3690 222.3690 226.3690
```

I would like to be able to extract multiple 5-minute averages for columns A, B and C based off time. Is there a way to do this where I would only need to type in the starting time period, rather than having to type the start AND end times for each time period I want to extract? Essentially, I want to be able to type the start time and have my code calculate and extract the average for the successive 5 minutes.

I was previously using the 'time.average' function from the 'openair' package to obtain 1-minute averages for the entire data set. I then created a vector with the start times and then used the 'subset' function' to extract the 1 minute averages I was interested in.

```
library(openair)
df.avg <- timeAverage(df, avg.time = "min", statistic = "mean")
cond.1.time <- c(
  '2020-03-06 10:09:00', 
  '2020-03-06 10:13:00',
  '2020-03-06 10:18:00',
) #enter start times
library(dplyr)
df.cond.1.avg <- subset(df.avg,
                           date %in% cond.1.time)  #filter data based off vector
df.cond.1.avg <- as.data.frame(df.cond.1.avg) #tibble to df
```

However, this approach will not work for 5-minute averages since not all of the time frames I am interested in begin in 5 minute increments of each other.  Also, my previous approach forced me to only use 1 minute averages that start at the top of the minute.

I need to be able to extract 5-minute averages scattered randomly throughout the day. These are not rolling averages.  I will need to extract approximately thirty 5-minute averages per day so being able to only type in the start date would be key.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries, the interval to be averaged can be selected by filtering the dates and averaged.
It doesn't seem to be efficient but it can help you.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-02-01 01:01:01"),
                              as.POSIXct("2020-02-01 20:01:10"),
                              by = "sec"),
                   A = rnorm(68410),
                   B = rnorm(68410),
                   C = rnorm(68410))

meanMinutes <- function(data, start, interval){
  # Interval in minutes
  start <- as.POSIXct(start)
  end <- start + 60*interval
  filterData <- dplyr::filter(data, date <= end, date >= start)
  date_start <- filterData$date[1]
  meanData <- filterData %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key = "param", value = "value", A:C) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(param) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    tidyr::spread(key = "param", value = "value")
  return(cbind(date_start, meanData))
}
```

For one date

```r
meanMinutes(data, "2020-02-01 07:03:11", 5)
```

Result:

```r
           date_start           A           B          C
1 2020-02-01 07:03:11 0.004083064 -0.06067075 -0.1304691
```

For multiple dates:

```r
dates <- c("2020-02-01 02:53:41", "2020-02-01 05:23:14", 
           "2020-02-01 07:03:11", "2020-02-01 19:10:45")
do.call(rbind, lapply(dates, function(x) meanMinutes(data, x, 5)))
```

Result:

```r
           date_start            A           B           C
1 2020-02-01 02:53:41 -0.001929374 -0.03807152  0.06072332
2 2020-02-01 05:23:14  0.009494321 -0.05911055 -0.02698245
3 2020-02-01 07:03:11  0.004083064 -0.06067075 -0.13046909
4 2020-02-01 19:10:45 -0.123574816 -0.02373881  0.05997007
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works great!  Is there a simple way to use this to also obtain the standard deviations for the same 5-minute periods?  I know I could rerun the code and change  'value=mean()' to 'value=sd()' and then perform a "cbind" to merge the two.  But would it be possible to manipulate the code to get both the mean and standard deviation in one go?

Comment: Yes, change in summarise: `dplyr::summarise(Mean = mean(value), SD = sd(value)  %>% tidyr::gather(key = "stat", value = "value", 2:3) %>%`